# How to add Hover to ToggleButton in Fxml file (Java17)

Tags: javafx, hover, togglebutton

```
<ToggleButton fx:id="toggleButton" text="xxxxxxxx" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;">
                <tooltip>
                    <Tooltip text="xxxxxxx"></Tooltip>
                </tooltip>
</ToggleButton>
```

How can highlight it`s background blue when mouse is on it?

I tried to use css but since i don`t really know the language im not sure if im doing it properly.

Comment: You have to do that in the external CSS stylesheet; you can't do it in FXML or do it easily in the controller.

Comment: For what it's worth, that change to the style in the FXML is probably futzing up whatever default hover action is already in the Modena stylesheet.  Since it usually works by changing the definition of one of the standard stylesheet colours in the "Hover" context.

Comment: @DaveB yes i know it seems ugly when in default so i wanted to change it.

Comment: Various [css styled buttons](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/).  The default styling is in `modena.css` file in the javafx controls jar of your javafx distribution.  It includes a demonstration of styling on hover.

Comment: Actually, there may be a way to do this. Try `style="-fx-color: transparent; -fx-hover-base: blue;"`. I still think using an external stylesheet is preferable, though.

Comment: I tried James's suggestion with the `style` setting, and could not get that to work with both the `fx-color` setting and the `fx-hover-base` setting. It did however appear to work with `-fx-hover-base` alone.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to define the styling for the hover action in an external styles.css file as suggested by James_D. Simply apply toggle button style like below.

Attach a stylesheet with your container or the control in the .fxml file (scene builder can bee used):

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" spacing="20.0" stylesheets="@../../../styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.javafxdemo.HelloController">
   
   <StackPane fx:id="myPane" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
         <ToggleButton fx:id="myToggleButton" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="My toggle button" />
      </children></StackPane>
</VBox>
```

styles.css file:

```
.toggle-button {
    /* default color here */
}
.toggle-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #178dfc;
}
```

Comment: a) don't hard-code sizing constraints b) why two entries in the css?

Comment: incorrect, suboptimal code is .. well incorrect, suboptimal code .. (and you can't know who downvoted, better not jump to conclusions ;) anyway, you might study the faq about voting on meta before requesting your own rules ..